# GARCH Covariance Matrix in Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to have the GARCH covariance matrix for my project and I want to know if this formula is correct:

in matlab using garchfit , we have "Innovations" and "Sigmas".To obtain a GARCH(1,1) Covariance matrix,Can we use:

"covariance=(correlation between Innovations)*(Sigmas*Sigmas')" ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you working with a multivariate GARCH, or what are you doing?